# Jquery Ajax success data from PHP echo not working

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get the data value on success from the php. However when I alert(data) in the success, it returns the page html.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="project_name" id="projectName" required>
```

Jquery AJAX:

```
$('#projectName').on('blur', function(){
    var projectName = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
            'projectChecked': 1,
            'project_name': projectName,
        },
        success: function(data){
            if (data == 'taken') {
                $('#projectName').addClass('border-red');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['projectChecked'])){
  echo 'taken'; 
  exit;
}
```

Alert Message:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png"/>

<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Meta Description">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlTw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-157194354-1"></script>
```

Comment: Inspect the actual response in browser dev tools network. That html could be an error page from server. The response tab within network will let you read what it says easily

Comment: The response tab is an exact copy of my html with the php echo 'taken' at the bottom of it.

Comment: Do you mean it looks like `<html>....</html>  taken`? If so there is nothing shown regarding output of the html and perhaps you need a different endpoint to send the ajax to

Comment: hmm it only shows whats in my header.php and then taken after it. <html><head></head><body>menu 'taken'

Comment: Well header.php shouldn't be included for this ajax. A new file and url for the ajax would probably be easier

Comment: Thank you, removing header.php fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You should use exit in php code to get return data use following code

```
if(isset($_POST['projectChecked'])){
  echo 'taken'; 
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check the html code when you do alert(data); and post here?

alternatively, you might want to check the developer tools of browser and validate network tab to monitor parameters and response of ajax request.

It is possible that you are getting http 400/500 response and you are actually seeing default error page (which is of course not a JSON response) in the data variable (this depends on the way server is configured)